# Reading lines from CSV files to build body request

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I'm creating a performance test with Jmeter and I need to create a body request like this:

```
{
  [ "objectName1", "objectName2", ..., "objectNameN" ]
}
```

so need to create a Groovy script to build this request according to a certain .csv file with the objects names. And I have done something like this:

```
//Default separator
char SEPARATOR = ',';

String csvFile = props.get("csvPathAndName")

log.info('__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________')
log.info(csvFile)

//function to read csv file
def readLines(String csvFile) {
    File file = new File(csvFile);
    List<String> objectNames = file.readLines();
//  objectsNames.stream().forEach(e -> listOfString + ", " + e);
    vars.put("listOfObjects", "'objectName1', 'objectName2', 'ObjectName3'");
}

readLines(csvFile)
```

Notice that in line

```
vars.put("listOfObjects", ...
```

I want to populate my listOfObjects with the values of my .csv file.
Someone can help me? I'm not really good at Groovy so I'm facing this problem now =//

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understood the desired result. What you're posting is not a correct JSON. Regarding putting a list of objects... why don't you just do `vars.put("listOfObjects", objectNames)`? Then your result would look like: `{"listOfObjects":["objectName1", "objectName2" etc.]}` Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change this line:

```
vars.put("listOfObjects", "'objectName1', 'objectName2', 'ObjectName3'");
```

to this one:

```
vars.put("listOfObjects", '"' + objectNames.join('","') + '"');
```

and amend your request body to:

```
{
  [ ${listOfObjects} ]
}
```

More information:

- [List.join() function](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#join(java.lang.String))
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this way. I've removed the last elements of the array to remove the end of file

```
, "
```

```
String csvFile = props.get("csvPathAndName")

log.info('__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________')
log.info(csvFile)

//function to read csv file
def readLines(String csvFile) {
    StringBuilder requestBody = new StringBuilder();
    File file = new File(csvFile);
    ArrayList<String> objectNames = file.readLines();
    objectNames.eachWithIndex {
        val, index ->
        if (index == 0) {
            requestBody.append(val + "\", ")
        } else {
            requestBody.append("\"" + val + "\", ")
        }
    }
    requestBody.setLength(requestBody.length() -3)
    vars.put("listOfObjects", requestBody.toString());
}

readLines(csvFile)
```

And my request body was just

```
[${listOfObjects}]
```